# Adding a drop down list based on RadioItems

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This code works fine. I can update graphics according to RadioItem. There is no dropdown in my dash now but I want to add 4 dropdown in total. 2 of them should be for the first RadioItem and 2 of them for the other RadioItem. In other words, I'll be updating my chart for the second time when I add the dropdowns. I could not find sample code for this situation. Here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

pp_list=['pp1', 'pp2', 'pp3', 'pp4', 'pp5', 'pp6', 'pp7', 'pp8']
group_list=['gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3', 'gr4', 'gr5', 'gr6', 'gr7', 'gr8']

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Markdown('''**Choose to Compare:**'''),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='radio',
        value='pp_basis',
        options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                 for x in ['pp_basis', 'group_basis']]
    ),

    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),

])

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    [Input("radio", "value")])
def display_(radio_value):

   
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    if radio_value == 'pp_basis':
        
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[2.1, 1.8, 1.3], name="pp1"),
        )

        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.9, 1.5, 0.8], name="pp2"),
        )

        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[300, 271, 311], mode='markers', name="secondary axis"),
            secondary_y=True,
        )

    else:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.5, 1.3, 1.38], name="gr1"),
        )

        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.3, 1.1, 1.18], name="gr2"),
        )

        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[300, 271, 311], mode='markers', name="secondary axis"),
            secondary_y=True,
        )

    
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="Cost Analysis"
    )

   
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="<b>Date</b>")

    
    if radio_value == 'pp_basis':
        fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text="<b>Cost</b>",
            )
    else:
        fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text="<b>WACC</b>",
        )

    fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="<b>Secondary Axis</b>",
        secondary_y=True)

    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I add two lists which are pp_list and group_list in the code. The result I want to design is as follows:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following changes to your code:

- Created a dropdown item in the app layout
- Created a callback with this new dropdown options/values as output and radio item value as input
- Adapted the graph creator callback to use the dropdown value as input

Now, based on a radio item selection, the dropdown options are refreshed.

```py
    import dash
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

    pp_list=['pp1', 'pp2', 'pp3', 'pp4', 'pp5', 'pp6', 'pp7', 'pp8']
    group_list=['gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3', 'gr4', 'gr5', 'gr6', 'gr7', 'gr8']

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Markdown('''**Choose to Compare:**'''),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='radio',
            value='pp_basis',
            options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                     for x in ['pp_basis', 'group_basis']]
        ),
        
        dcc.Dropdown(id= 'dropdown'),

        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),

    ])

    @app.callback(
        [Output('dropdown', 'options'),
         Output('dropdown', 'value')],
        Input('radio', 'value'))

    def dropdown_options(radio_value):
        
        if radio_value == 'pp_basis':
            options = [{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in pp_list]
            value = pp_list[0]
        else:
            options = [{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in group_list]
            value = group_list[0]
        
        return options, value
        
    @app.callback(
        Output("graph", "figure"),
        [Input("dropdown", "value")])

    #here you will define what the graph should look like based on the dropdown
    def display_(dropdown_value):

        fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

        if dropdown_value.startswith('pp'):
            
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[2.1, 1.8, 1.3], name="pp1"),
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.9, 1.5, 0.8], name="pp2"),
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[300, 271, 311], mode='markers', name="secondary axis"),
                secondary_y=True,
            )

        else:
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.5, 1.3, 1.38], name="gr1"),
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[1.3, 1.1, 1.18], name="gr2"),
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(x=['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'], y=[300, 271, 311], mode='markers', name="secondary axis"),
                secondary_y=True,
            )

        
        fig.update_layout(
            title_text="Cost Analysis"
        )

       
        fig.update_xaxes(title_text="<b>Date</b>")

        
        if dropdown_value.startswith('pp'):
            fig.update_yaxes(
                title_text="<b>Cost</b>",
                )
        else:
            fig.update_yaxes(
                title_text="<b>WACC</b>",
            )

        fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text="<b>Secondary Axis</b>",
            secondary_y=True)

        return fig

    app.run_server(debug=True, port=5050, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I wanted to add 2 dropdown lists, but I should understand the logic of this code.

Comment: I got it done. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Your welcome, you can see another example of this case in the following link: https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks in the section "Dash App With Chained Callbacks"